# Swift self in static method

Tags: swift

I want to use self in static method as class type, but I'm getting compile time error.

Here is my test code:

```
protocol JSONMappable {
    static func map(JSON: AnyObject!) -> Self
}

class Model : JSONMappable, Mappable {   
    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

    }

    static func map(JSON: AnyObject!) -> Self {
        return Mapper<self>().map(JSON)
    }   
}
```

So in static method map I want to use self as class type, I also tried self.Type, but I'm getting same error. I don't want to use class name, because I need this method to use `subclass` class name when it will be called on `subclass`. for example if I will have:

```
class SubClass : Model {

}
```

and call:

```
SubClass.map(JSON)
```

I need to have `SubClass` in this method instead of `Model`.
So I'm wonder if this possible to do?

Comment: why would you need to return self?

Comment: @Lukas the attempt here is to return an instance of the type

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol A {
    static func f()->Self
}
// class should conform to protocol A, so the returned type should be B
final class B: A {
    static func f() -> B {
        return B()
    }
}

let b = B()
let c = B.f()
```

I don't see any practical usage, because final class could not be subclassed and to implemet your protocol, the class should be declared as final

by the way, this means the same

```
protocol A {
    static func f()->Self
}

final class B: A {
    class func f() -> B {
        return B()
    }
}
```

without static

```
protocol A {
    func f()->Self
}

class B: A {
    func f()->Self {
        return self
    }
}
let a = B()
let b = a.f()
```